# Xamarin EditText content on scroll

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

I'm writing in Xamarin Android and I'm trying to handle with problem  of scroling in ListView. When I scroll down, and up again EditText lose value entered previously. I wrote custom adapter with ViewHolder patter. Unfortunetly my adapter dont work properly, it mixed entered data to random(?) rows.

This is my adapter. Could someone tell me where is the problem in my code?

```
public class Adapter: BaseAdapter<Product>
{

   private List<Product> MyItems;
   private Context MyContext;
   public string[] Current;
   Dictionary<int, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

   public Adapter(Context context, List<Product> items)
   {
       MyContext = context;
       MyItems = items;
        Current = new string[items.Count];
       for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
       {
           myDictionary.Add(i, "0");

       }

   }
    public override Product this[int position]
    {
        get { return MyItems[position]; }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return MyItems.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int nPostion = position;

        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(MyContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.productRowOrder, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv1 =row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.productOrderId);
            holder.tv1.Text = "" + MyItems[position].id;
            holder.tv2 =row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.productOrderName);
            holder.tv2.Text = MyItems[position].name;
            holder.tv3 =row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.productOrderStock);
            holder.tv3.Text = "" + MyItems[position].quantity;
            holder.tv4 =row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.productOrderUnit);
            holder.tv4.Text = "" + MyItems[position].unit;
            holder.tv5 =row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.productOrderPriceNet);
            holder.tv5.Text = "" + MyItems[position].priceNet;
            holder.tv6 = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.productOrderPriceGross);
            holder.tv6.Text = "" + MyItems[position].priceGross;

            holder.et1 = row.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.productOrderQuantity);


            row.Tag = holder;
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)row.Tag;
        }

        holder.et1.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Current[holder.pos] = args.Editable.ToString();
            myDictionary[nPostion] = args.Editable.ToString().Trim();
        };



         holder.pos = position;

holder.et1.Text = myDictionary[position];


        return row;
    }

    private class ViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public TextView tv1;
        public TextView tv2;
        public TextView tv3;
        public TextView tv4;
        public TextView tv5;
        public TextView tv6;
        public EditText et1;
        public int pos;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code, this line `holder.et1.Text = myDictionary[position];`  is where the edittext's value is set when we scroll the listview. So there is a high possibility that the data source `myDictionary` is in disorder. This line `myDictionary[nPostion] = args.Editable.ToString().Trim();`is where we put the   specific value into the edittext.

My solution is that you may try this line `myDictionary[nPostion] = holder.et1.getText().ToString().Trim();`instead of `myDictionary[nPostion] = args.Editable.ToString().Trim();`.(I have not used  Xamarin before so i use getText() ~). I hope this change can be useful to fix your bug.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this not solved my problem. Now i have another: getView gets wrong position, so when i enter value in row 1 it is in row 6 too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "AfterTextChanged" handler, handle "FocusChange" event...
It will solve your problem in Xamarin...

Good Luck.

--- Code Sample ---

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
        var row = convertView;

        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.StudentScore_item, null, false);
        }

        var lblScoreId = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lblScoreID);
        lblScoreId.Text = mItems[position].ID.ToString();

        var tbxScore_Final = row.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.tbxScore_Final);
        tbxScore_Final.Typeface = fontType;
        tbxScore_Final.Text =
            (mItems[position].FinalScore.HasValue ? mItems[position].FinalScore.ToString() : "");
        tbxScore_Final.Tag = mItems[position].ID;
        tbxScore_Final.FocusChange += (sender, e) =>
        {
            EditText tbx = sender as EditText;
            decimal score;
            bool isValidScore = decimal.TryParse(tbx.Text, out score);
            if (isValidScore)
            {
                int inx = FindScoreIndex((int)tbx.Tag);

                Log.WriteLine(
                    LogPriority.Info,
                    "Infooo",
                    string.Format(
                        "INDEX = {0} | ID = {1} | DATA = {2} | Validated = {3} | ==> {4}",
                        inx,
                        tbx.Tag.ToString(),
                        tbx.Text,
                        score.ToString(),
                        mItems[inx].ID
                    )
                );

                mItems[inx].FinalScore = score;
            }
        };

        return row;
    }
```